# oracle report changint column width

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

I try change column width by `choosing : proprty inspector->column->width` but width is locked I cant't change value, where can be problem

Answer (score 1):

The column width you are referring to is the size of the data column in your data model. For instance, if you have a database column as `varchar2(10)` and you query that column in your report's data model, then the width will be 10. And if you base a field in the report layout on this data column, it's width will also be 10. That's not something you can change. But, if you are trying to just make a field in your report layout *wider*, then just use the graphical layout editor to size the column (click and drag the edge with your mouse).